# When installing an R package, automatically reinstall dependencies when needed

Tags: r, installation, dependencies

`utils::install.packages` seems to be perfectly capable of installing dependencies that are missing. But if there's a dependency that's already installed without being of the right version for some reason (e.g., when trying to install `DiagrammeR`, `Error: package ‘igraph’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version`), the original `install.packages` call just stops there. I then have to go and manually reinstall each problematic dependency. How can I automate this?

I'm running R 3.6.1 on Linux.

Comment: It is partially a "thinko" on your end:  the "implicit contract" you have with `install.packages()` is that it can assume your _already installed packages are current_.  You are suppose to run `update.packages()` as well, which takes care of that part.  By being current to the CRAN versions _of your installed packages_ you pretty much ensure that the to-be-installed package will work with them.  (Installation may still fail for lack of system libraries or other tools that `install.packages()` has no control over.)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It seems that `update.packages` (is that what you meant?) upgrades every package that's installed, which would presumably suffice, but is overkill.

Comment: It is not overkill. That is how the system is designed and works.  I run `update.packages()` essentially daily on my machine(s), and it only ever updates a handful of packages (in parallel, using the `Ncpus` option).  I think you are caught in a mental block where you want _both_ total stability and no changes, yet flawless installation of any additional package. But that is not a service guarantee CRAN gives you so you have to do something else: it is a square beg / round hole problem.  YMMV.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Not at all, I just want the changes that are necessary to perform an installation or update I ask for, and no more than that.

Comment: I hear you. I just tried to explain three times that your assumptions are not valid for the task so it is not surprising to me you hit a wall.  Step back, and think through what `install.packages()` would do for your new package if you did not have the others (in a partially stale state) installed.  They would all be fresh to CRAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is crude (especially since it will happily redownload a package multiple times), but it's the best I've come up with so far:

```
install.rec = function(pkg, repos = 'http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran')
# Install a package and reinstall any dependencies that need
# to be reinstalled, recursively.
   {while (T)
       {message("INSTALLING: ", pkg)
        out = paste0(collapse = " ",
            system2("Rscript", stdout = T, stderr = T, sprintf(
                "--no-init-file -e \"install.packages('%s', repos='%s')\"",
                pkg, repos)))
        p = regmatches(out, regexec(text = out, perl = T,
            "package ‘(\\S+)’ was installed (?:before R|by an R version)"))[[1]]
        if (length(p))
           {p = p[2]
            message("START RECURSING: ", pkg, " - ", p)
            install.rec(p, repos)
            message("END RECURSING: ", pkg, " - ", p)}
        else
            break}
   message("DONE WITH: ", pkg)}
```

`install.packages` doesn't raise conditions, nor does it return errors, nor does it produce its output in a way captureable with `capture.output`, so we have to use a system call to see the error message. The idea comes from [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Capture-output-of-install-packages-pipe-system2-tp4676754p4676787.html).

Comment: You can do better just with base R (if you care).  `installed.packages()` gives you what you have, `available.packages()` gives you what is out there (and is enough for "overall behindness" of your installation). Pair that that with the fabulous `tools::CRAN_package_db()` for dependency information and then you can walk you graph.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Is the check that `install.packages` uses to stop with "installed by an R version with different internals" just that the major and minor R version when the package was installed match that of your current R?

Comment: I do not the answer to this question. It could be internal to the package, or a `try/catch` error answer when trying to load it.  I do not know how I as a package author could signal this.   In any event, and without trying to hurt your feelings, I think you are reinventing existing wheels ...   You could always ask on r-devel.

Comment: "I think you are reinventing existing wheels" — I know; that's the frustrating part. But I suppose it's good enough for now.

Comment: I also noticed that you mentioned Debian. That is the other issue -- I also maintain 100+ `r-cran-*` packages, and have for a long time. But we don't have an integrated package manager either, because the problem is effin' *hard*. And there are no perfect "other" solutions either for Python, Ruby, Julia, Go, Elisp, ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yeah, I already use a custom-installed Python instead of the system Python, so arguably I should just bite the bullet and do the same for R.

Comment: (hushed voice)  Which is what I do for CRAN packages along with the CRAN mirror for the updated R binary.  I actually _like_ the daily cadence.  Look at script `install.r` and `update.r` in the `examples` director of package `littler` aka `r-cran-littler` ....

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to enforce this in `install.packages()`. Instead, you could use `pak::pkg_install()`. From `pak::pkg_install()` "upgrade" argument :

```
upgrade 
Whether to upgrade already installed packages to the latest available version. If this is 
FALSE, then only packages that need updates to satisfy version requirements, will be 
updated. If it is TRUE, all specified or dependent packages will be updated to the latest 
available version.
```

Edit: Reading your question more carefully, it sounds like you might be using a 3.5 package library with 3.6. If that's the case, I recommend the R package [installr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/installr/index.html) when upgrading between versions. It can automate the re-installation of all packages you had in the previous version.

Edit2: The below code will show you which are built on the previous version. I would run `install.packages(built_on_earlier_version, force = TRUE)` for these packages.

```
installed_packages <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())

installed_packages[as.package_version(installed_packages$Built) < as.package_version("3.6.0"),]
```

Comment: This function sounds like it would upgrade all dependencies unconditionally, whether they need an upgrade to make the original package usable or not, which is overkill, but better than nothing.

Comment: @Kodiologist That's not quite correct. If `upgrade=FALSE`, it will only update package dependencies if necessary to meet another package's version requirements for that dependency. I believe this is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like all `pak::pkg_install` does to check if a dependency is good, at least with `upgrade = FALSE`, is to check the version of the installed dependency; it does not check that the dependency can actually be loaded. Thus, `pak::pkg_install("DiagrammeR")` seems to work, but then `library(DiagrammeR)` yields `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DiagrammeR’: package ‘rgexf’ was installed by an R version with different internals; it needs to be reinstalled for use with this R version`, just like `install.packages("DiagrammeR")` does.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I think this problem is due to using a package library from a different version of R, i.e. 3.5 instead of 3.6

Comment: Are you suggesting that I call `installr::updateR`? I fear that wouldn't play well with the Debian package manager's own management of R. Also, the documentation of the function suggests that it will update *all* your packages, which includes packages I've forgotten I have and will never use again. `pak::pkg_install(upgrade = T)` is less overkill than that.

Comment: `installr::updateR()` would be my general advice when a new version of R comes out, but probably not what you want to do now. I don't use R on Linux enough to comment on what a good strategy is. See my latest edit for seeing which packages you need to upgrade from an earlier version of R.

Comment: `built_on_earlier_version` isn't specific to the dependencies in question, but if you can enumerate the dependencies (recursively), one could then set-intersect the dependencies with `built_on_earlier_version`, then `install.packages` the result, and I think that would do it.